# How to require one of two packages to be present?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi, requirements

I maintain a Python module. There are two existing modules on PyPi which provide a functionality that is mandatory for my project to work. They don't conflict with each other in any way.

I'd like my users to have freedom of choice regarding the implementation, as either of those has some pros and cons.

How can I construct the `setup.py` so that it requires one (or both) of those modules to be installed but signals an error when none is present?